# What's the difference between electromagnets and induced magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am studying over the **basic** introductory concepts of magnetism, and I cannot comprehend definition of the following words below:

**Electromagnets**- objects that are magnetic only when electric current is flowing.

**induced magnetism**- magnetism that is present only when an electric current is flowing.

The only difference that I notice is the object and magnetism, yet it seems that those two words relate so much to each other.

Comment: We usually talk about induced magnetism of ferromagnets that are near or in contact with permanent magnets.

Answer (score 1):

An electromagnet is a magnet only when current is flowing through it. Materials which are used to make electromagnets have particular properties, specifically low *retentivity* and low *coercivity*. Retentivity is the property of a material which makes it retain a bit of the magnetic field once the *magnetic intensity* reduces to 0. While coercivity is the *magnetic intensity* required to erase that amount of magnetic field the material retained when the external *magnetic intensity* was made zero.

Permanent magenta on the other hand are usually made from materials which have a high *retentivity* and high *coercivity*. Basically a permanent magnet is made by placing a ferromagnetic material inside solenoid and applying a field. Because of the aforementioned characteristics of a permanent magnetic, it gets a net *magnetisation* when the external magnetic field is removed.

I'd like to suggest you to familiarise yourself with the *italicised words* for a better understanding of the definitions you've mentioned.

Basically both are due to current. But one (**electromagnets**) stops being magnetic when the external current producing the field is switched off. While the other (permanent magnets produced by **magnetic induction**) remains magnetic when the current stops because of a net magnetisation.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a scrapyard and the electromagnet that is hung by cables from a crane to pick up, say cars. This electromagnets needs a constant current running  through it to maintain the magnetic effect.

So the electric current induces a magnetic effect in the iron base of the electromagnet. It's the physical process of induced magnetism that creates the electromagnet.